# Java: Palindrome, not getting biggest number

Tags: java, palindrome

I want to get the largest palindrome number of 3-digit numbers. This is my code:

```
for (int start = 100; start < 1000; start++) {
        for (int start2 = 100; start2 < 1000; start2++) {
            int temp = start * start2;  
            int biggest = 1;
            String strTemp = temp + "";     

            if (strTemp.equals(new StringBuilder(strTemp).reverse().toString())) {
                if (temp > biggest) {
                    biggest = temp;
                    System.out.println("Original: " + strTemp);
                    System.out.println("Reverse: " + new StringBuilder(strTemp).reverse().toString());
                    System.out.println("Siffra: " + start);
                    System.out.println("Siffra2: " + start2);
                }

            }       
        }
```

In the end, I get `995 x 583` and not `993 x 913`, which is the largest one. Why? I have it so the int biggest always chooses the biggest number.

Comment: is this from project Euler?..

Comment: Nit: you can start the `start2` loop at `start2 = start`, otherwise you will check both `a * b` and `b * a`.

Comment: @AndyTurner How do you mean? Do you have an example code on that? I do not really follow how to structure the code.

Comment: `for (int start2 = start; start2 < 1000; start2++) {`

Comment: Now I understand! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move int `biggest = 1;` out of both for loops.
If you don't do that at every inner loop you restart the value of biggest.

```
int biggest = 1;
for (int start = 100; start < 1000; start++) {
    for (int start2 = 100; start2 < 1000; start2++) {
        int temp = start * start2;  

        String strTemp = temp + "";     

        if (strTemp.equals(new StringBuilder(strTemp).reverse().toString())) {
            if (temp > biggest) {
                biggest = temp;
                System.out.println("Original: " + strTemp);
                System.out.println("Reverse: " + new StringBuilder(strTemp).reverse().toString());
                System.out.println("Siffra: " + start);
                System.out.println("Siffra2: " + start2);
            }

        }       
    }
```

With java 8 you can rewrite this code as follow:

```
    // Define what it means palindrome
    IntPredicate isPalindrome = n -> new StringBuffer(String.valueOf(n)).reverse().toString().equals(String.valueOf(n));


    OptionalInt max = 
             // Define a stream from 100 to 1000
             IntStream.range(100, 1000)   
             // Map the original stream to a new stream 
             // Basically for each x of the first stream
             // creates a new stream 100-1000 and map each element
             // x of the first stream and y of the second stream
             // to x * y
            .flatMap(x -> IntStream.range(100, 1000).map(y -> x * y))
             // Take only palyndrome of x * y
            .filter(isPalindrome)
            // take the max
            .max();
```

A functional approach is more readable in most cases where you have to loop over n elements and is easier to filter and extract elements without
doing errors.

Comment: @Aminorph this is where your debugger would have been able to help you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Move your declaration of `biggest` outside the loops:

```
int biggest = 1;
for (int start = 100; start < 1000; start++) {
        for (int start2 = 100; start2 < 1000; start2++) {
            int temp = start * start2;  
            String strTemp = temp + "";     

            if (strTemp.equals(new StringBuilder(strTemp).reverse().toString())) {
                if (temp > biggest) {
                    biggest = temp;
                    System.out.println("Original: " + strTemp);
                    System.out.println("Reverse: " + new StringBuilder(strTemp).reverse().toString());
                    System.out.println("Siffra: " + start);
                    System.out.println("Siffra2: " + start2);
                }

            }       
        }
```

Output:

```
....
Original: 906609                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Reverse: 906609                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Siffra: 913                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Siffra2: 993
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int biggest = 1;    
for (int start = 100; start < 1000; start++) {
            for (int start2 = 100; start2 < 1000; start2++) {
                int temp = start * start2;
```

in above you are `initializing biggest=1` always. so you not getting proper result. Keep it outside of for loop.